# ExpressJS Twig module not allowing async despite setting the options accordingly

Tags: javascript, express, twig.js

I'm trying to load an array from mongoose into a twig rendered list , blocking on an error that says:

> TwigException: You are using Twig.js in sync mode in combination with
>   async extensions.

So I've followed the instructions in the official twigjs documentation , yet even with :

```
app.set("twig options",{allow_async:true})
```

it's not working!
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

So **this was a version issue** , the updated version (actual : **1.15.0** ) doesn't really allow for async (defunct) , however a *rollback* to **version 1.12.0** **successfully corrected the issue.**